# VBA ComboBox text will not remain

Tags: vba, text, combobox

ComboBox will not remember/store text unless I type it in.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.List = Array("0", "0.1", "0.2")
End Sub
```

The text value then determines CommandButton function.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If ComboBox1.Text = "0" Then
        Call Name0
    End If
    If ComboBox1.Text = "0.1" Then
        Call Name1
    End If
    If ComboBox1.Text = "0.2" Then
        Call Name2
    End If
End Sub
```

The code works, just doesn't keep the array in combobox.

Comment: look at the designer property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264339.aspx

Comment: @litelite what's the `Designer` having anything to do with this?

Comment: sorry if i misunderstood, but you said you want your change to persist right?

Comment: I was going to use a combobox to change value for if statement. Option button works and looks better on the form. Thanks anyways for your help!

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
        Call Name_0
        End If
        If OptionButton2.Value = True Then
        Call Name1
        End If
            If OptionButton3.Value = True Then
            Call Name2
            End If
       End Sub

Answer (score 0):

This seem to work out best and looks better on the form..
Not the answer to my question but another avenue to solving it.
Cheers!

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
       If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
        Call Name_0
         End If
          If OptionButton2.Value = True Then
           Call Name1
            End If
           If OptionButton3.Value = True Then
        Call Name2
       End If
   End Sub
```